# Dapper converting C# decimal to SQL decimal instead of money (Always Encrypted)

Tags: c#, dapper, always-encrypted

Using Dapper to save data that is decimal which is meant to go into an AlwaysEncrypted money field is resulting in this error:

Operand type clash: decimal(5,1) encrypted with (...)
is incompatible with money encrypted with (...)

How do you explicitly tell Dapper to use money as the type as C# Decimal <-> Money is the preferred mapping?

```
decimal income = 4500m;
using (var connection = new ReliableSqlConnection(connectionString)) {
   try {
   connection.Open(); 
   connection.Query<int>(
    @"INSERT INTO [tablename]
           ([MonthlyAfterTaxIncome])
      VALUES
           (@MonthlyAfterTaxIncome);
      SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)",
                        new {
                            MonthlyAfterTaxIncome = income
                        })
                    .FirstOrDefault();
              } finally {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
```

Column Details:

```
 [MonthlyAfterTaxIncome] [money] ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [KeyName],         ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NOT NULL,)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SqlMapper.AddTypeMap(typeof(decimal), DbType.Currency);
```

Has replaced the default mapping of decimal to DbType.Decimal removing the source of the problem.